# My collection's maximum size is not sufficient for computation, what can I do about it?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

Working with `ArrayList`, its size grows exponentially with each iteration and, over time, the collection becomes too small to continue the computation.

With each iteration, you need to change each element and, according to some condition, add more new elements. My code worked for 100 iterations, but now it needs 256 and it can't handle it anymore.

It turns out a very large flow of calculations, size exceeds `int` and  I need to continue computing in `long`, but `ArrayList` cant do it due to size restrictions.

I guess that at a certain stage I need to create new `ArrayList`'s, also iterate over each of them multithreaded, adding new data to the new one, without hitting the limit of `ArrayList'`s sizes.

How can I realize that? Initial size of my `ArrayList` is 300, each value is a number from 0 to 5.

Here is the code for my methods:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> old = new ArrayList<>();
//here is filling my array with 300 elements, too much numbers, don't want to dirty the question with them
//now I call the killer method, the capacity of which is no longer enough
    calculateNew(256, old); //it was worked for 100 iterarions, but now i need 256 and he cant do it
    old.size(); //accordingly, I need to calculate this value after 256 iterations

}

static void calculateNew(int days, ArrayList<Integer> old){
    for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
            
        oneDayNew(old);
        System.out.println("Day " + (i+1<10? i+1 + " " : i+1) + ": size of school: " + old.size());
        }
    }

static void oneDayNew(ArrayList<Integer> old){
        int countNew = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < old.size(); i++){
            if(old.get(i) == 0) {
                countNew++;
                old.set(i, 7);
            }
            if(old.get(i) > 0) {
                int temp = old.get(i);
                old.set(i, --temp);
            }
        }
        
        if(countNew > 0 ){
            for(int i = 0; i < countNew; i++){
                old.add(8);
            }
        }
    }
```

What can I do? Multi-threading? Array of `ArrayList`s? I'm looking for hints, not a ready-made solution.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: @kiner_shah It Runs over ArrayList,, subtracting -1 from each element, if element is zero - add a new element to the end and changes element's value(zero) to 7. It turns out a kind of geometrically increasing ArrayList,. Needs to do 256 iterations of the method oneDay and get the size of the collection (number of items)

Comment: And why are you doing all these steps? What is the problem statement?

Comment: How far do you need to go? Do you even have enough memory for the computation? Looks like you only need to know the final size of the list, perhaps you can devise an algorithm to count the numbers without storing them all in a list? You can, for example, store a histogram - an int[] of how many numbers 0-8 you have, that would use constant memory and would be an O(N) algorithm where yours is O(scary). If you want to follow your way, you can look into libraries with big lists, like https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/#big

Comment: @PetrJaneček  Thank you mister for the detailed answer, I read about histograms, a very interesting method of processing by grouping the same values!

Comment: @LexBekker Were you able to solve the problem with a different approach? Do you still need any help and/or guidance?

Answer (score 1):

The size of school after 256 iterations is over 350 billion (starting with 300 random elements sized 0-8). Even if every number was 1 byte, which it isn't, it would need over 350 GB of memory. As it stands, it needs 10* that. Therefore, your approach unfortunately does not scale. This is common for brute force algorithms. You do not want to store every number separately, and you definitely do not want to process them one by one.

Change your data structure.

For example, you can group the numbers together and only store how many of each numbers you have, using a `long[]` as a histogram. That way, `histogram[0]` would store how many zeros you have, `histogram[1]` would store how many ones you have, etc. all the way up to your max value. Of course, a `Map<Integer, Long>` would work just as well for the purpose. That way, you only use constant memory, and you process much fewer numbers per iteration as they are grouped together.